# Bluemix IBM Graph service - Create vertices

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases

I am trying to create a vertex using the vertices API.

Please take a look at the following snippet.

```
def create_vertex(self,creds,id):
    creds = json.load(open(creds))
    print(creds)
    url = creds['credentials']['apiURL'] + '/vertices'    
    start = time.time()
    res = requests.post(
        url,
        auth=(
            creds['credentials']['username'],
            creds['credentials']['password']
        ),
        data=json.dumps([{"id":"256"}]),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    )

    res.raise_for_status()
    print 'query took %s seconds' % (time.time() - start)
    return res.json()
```

The curl on the API url is working fine and I received the following response

```
{
    "requestId":"49646d73-0073-450a-9976-57049821fa42",
    "status":{
        "message":"",
        "code":200,
        "attributes":{}
    },
    "result":{
        "data":["StandardTitanGraph"],
        "meta":{}
    }
 }
```

and I guess this response is correct.

But the API URLs are giving me the following errors.

> raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
>   requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway

Comment: I am fairly sure that you are referencing the Graph Data Store experimental service, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is experimental. Today I deleted the old instance and created a new instance and it is not even validating my credentials.

Comment: This is the response I got -- `{"status_code":500,"info":"internal server error"}`

Comment: munx opened a ticket with Bluemix Support, which resulted in an internal fix. The issue has been resolved, but there isn't an "answer" to this question that can be provided. If someone else encounters this issue in the future, they can open a ticket with Bluemix Support.

Answer (score 2):

As Bill mentioned above this issue has been fixed in the latest release of the service. Please try it again and update this Question.

In order to get the latest update you will need to create a new service https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/graph-data-store/ and run your program against.